# How to call Intent in other activity using putExtra

Tags: android, android-intent

this is my code and I want to use this activity in my different class where I have put my TextView to show saved data.

```
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            String content = tv.getText().toString();


            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowNote.class);
            i.putExtra("Title", content);
            //i.putExtra("id", getListView.get(arg2).getID());
            startActivity(i);
```

What does this code mean. i just dont understand putExtra values

```
              i.putExtra("Title", content);
              i.putExtra("id", getListView.get(arg2).getID());
```

Please help to me to understand this code.

Answer (score 0):

`i.putExtra("Title", content);` it defines that you are passing some data from one activity to another activity to access.

To understand more about `Intent` check out [Link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

You're putting some information in your intent, so the called Activity can extract them, and do it's business logic based on it

Answer (score 0):

Its Simple but its hard to understand as a beginner.

`i.putExtra("Title", content);`

You passing value from one activity to another activity.

In this above line of code `Title` is a key. By which the second activity come to know about the value you sent. Thats same for `i.putExtra("id", getListView.get(arg2).getID());`.

Hope it helps.